# Is it possible to create a File object from InputStream

Tags: java, io

Is there any way to create a `java.io.File` object from an `java.io.InputStream` ?

My requirement is reading the File from a RAR . I am not trying to write a temporary File, I have a file inside RAR archive which I am trying to read.

Comment: my requirement is reading the File from a RAR . Assume i am not try to write the temporary File from the RAR, inside RAR i am having a File, just i need to read.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify. If you want the oriinal File from the InputStream, there wasn't one: you are reading a RAR file, not a File. If you want something else, what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert InputStream to virtual File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317035/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-virtual-file)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You need to create new file and copy contents from `InputStream` to that file:

```
File file = //...
try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)){
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception here
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception here
}
```

I am using convenient [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to avoid manual copying of streams. Also it has built-in buffering.

Comment: Couldn't resolve IOUtils in Android Studio and the link you referenced is a 404.

Comment: org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io needed to be added as a dependency. My bad. :)

Comment: Please close correctly the OutputStream, use a try with resources or IOUtils.closeQuietly. I know its just an example but beginners will copy it literally.

Comment: Can anyone explain File file = //... ? How do I initialize the file first?

Answer (score 94):

In one line :

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file);
```

(org.apache.commons.io)

Answer (score 59):

Since Java 7, you can do it in one line even without using any external libraries:

```
Files.copy(inputStream, outputPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

See the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Comment: If you use this with Android, a min SDK of 26 is required.

Answer (score 40):

Create a temp file first using org.apache.commons.io.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
return tempFile;
```

Comment: Please Include package name of IOUtils

Comment: org.apache.commons.io

Comment: It also exists in org.apache.axis2.util with a third parameter for the copy function. The functionality works there too. Any comparisons on what to use?

Answer (score 13):

### Easy Java 9 solution with *try with resources* block

```
public static void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream input, File file) {  

    try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        input.transferTo(output);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[java.io.InputStream#transferTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) is available since Java 9.

Comment: Which part of it makes it require Java 11?

Comment: @MauriceNino My bad, thanks for a comment "try-with-resources – introduced in Java 7"

Answer (score 11):

If you do not want to use other libraries, here is a simple function to copy data from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Now, you can easily write an `Inputstream` into a file by using `FileOutputStream`-

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
copyStream (inputStream, out);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java version 7 or higher, you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to properly close the `FileOutputStream`. The following code use [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) from [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

```
public void copyToFile(InputStream inputStream, File file) throws IOException {
    try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to close the OutputStream? Like in the answer from Tomasz N.

Comment: @trinity420 Resources specified in the `try` initialization part are automatically closed when the `try` block is exited.

Comment: is this applicable for android?

Comment: @gumuruh Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24290875/89769

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is for Java but this comes up big on Google for Android searches as well, and a lot of modern Android uses Kotlin. So here's how easy it is in Kotlin, no 3rd party libs needed at all: `inputstream.copyTo(os)`

A more fleshed out example:

```
// I'm loading my InputStream from resources, you can get it anywhere
val inputstream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ronan_collins)
// getCacheDir is /data/data/com.your.packagename/cache if you forgot. 
// Which is probably the best place on Android to create tmp files
val outputFile = File(cacheDir, "output.jpg")
val os = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
inputstream.copyTo(os)
```

And now your file is /data/data/com.your.packagename/cache/output.jpg.
And if you're wondering based on the SO question title, you can't create a `File` object from an `InputStream` without creating a real file somewhere, you can't write to a virtual file or a `File` object in memory or something like that.