# try-with-resources are not supported at this language level - Android

Tags: android, try-with-resources, notsupportedexception

I have a problem with "try-with-resources are not supported at this language level" in android in the following posted code, I tried to set language to 7 but it stills keeps giving me the same example plus it keeps giving me the option to change to language 7.

```
public String ReadFile(String fileName) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName+".txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        String everything = sb.toString();
        return everything;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SaveNLoadRank.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SaveNLoadRank.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return "1";
}
```

Comment: Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22303654/2649012, where it's explained that `Try-with-resources requires minSdkVersion 19`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 7 language features with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*try-with-resources* is only supported if your `minSdkVersion` is set to 19 or higher.

Since I doubt your application support a minimum API version of 19 or higher (in June of 2014), that is likely your problem.

Support for Java 7 language features was added in SDK Tools Revision 22.6 released in March of 2014 ([see here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)). However, *try-with-resources* is not a feature that is possible to introduce for previous versions of Android, so applications using that feature must run on 19+, thus the `minSdkVersion` requirement.

**UPDATE**
You can now use try-with-resources with any API.

> In addition to the Java 8 language features and APIs above, Android
> Studio 3.0 and later extends support for try-with-resources to all
> Android API levels.
>
> To start using supported Java 8 language features, update the Android plugin to 3.0.0 (or higher). After that, for each module that uses Java 8 language features (either in its source code or through dependencies), update the Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility to 1.8 in the Project Structure dialog as shown in figure 2 (click File > Project Structure).

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: @user3272243- Unfortunately you need to have a min of 10. Otherwise your application would be available on devices that do not support try-with-resources.

Comment: I was able to fix it making smaller portions of try catchs, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: +1 for the update - I knew something weird was happening when my external libs used try with resources just fine but Andriod studio was not letting me use it in my app. I do agree with @JemshitIskenderov here though - the API version you choose to support is your decision, not a "problem".

Comment: I was curious how this support was implemented, so researched a bit and wrote [a blogpost](https://blog.osom.info/2019/10/try-with-resources-desugaring-support.html) that shows how dx/d8 desugaring works.

Comment: FWIW, running Android Studio 3.6, it keeps asking to use try-with-resources while min SDK is set to 14! I had to use 'suppress for statement'. Quite annoying and dangerous because using try-with-resources will crash on any Android lower than 19!

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported below API 19, but it reportedly works on 15 and maybe even 14: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73483