# How to store the selected Image from Google Drive?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to send the selected image the user selected from their Google Drive to another function. I would like retrieve the content the user selected and send the photo uri or a bitmap of that photo to a function. Can anyone help me out?

This is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Google Drive Activity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
    private static final  int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 2;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean fileOperation = false;
    private DriveId mFileId;
    public DriveFile file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside the onCreate Method");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity will start interacting with the user.
     * At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack,
     * with user input going to it.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside the onResume method");
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

            /**
             * Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
             * We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection failures.
             * Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating the API client");
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"About to call connect method().");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"inside the onStop method");
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

            // disconnect Google API client connection
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onConnectionFailed()");
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

        if (!result.hasResolution()) {

            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }

        /**
         *  The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
         *  Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an  authorization
         *  dialog is displayed to the user.
         */

        try {

            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * It invoked when Google API client connected
     * @param connectionHint
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onConnected Method()");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * It invoked when connection suspend
     * @param cause
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    public void onClickCreateFile(View view){
        fileOperation = true;

        // create new contents resource
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);

    }

    public void onClickOpenFile(View view){
        fileOperation = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Selected the onClickOpenFile button");
        // create new contents resource
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }

    /**
     *  Open list of folder and file of the Google Drive
     */
    public void OpenFileFromGoogleDrive(){

        Log.i(TAG, "Inside OpenFIleFromGoogleDrive method.");
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                //Restricting the user to only select txt and image support files for Tesseract.
                .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "jpg" })
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(

                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This is Result result handler of Drive contents.
     * this callback method call CreateFileOnGoogleDrive() method
     * and also call OpenFileFromGoogleDrive() method,
     * send intent onActivityResult() method to handle result.
     */
    final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Inside onResultCallback()");
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        if (fileOperation == true) {

                            CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(result);

                        } else {

                            OpenFileFromGoogleDrive();

                        }
                    }

                }
            };

    /**
     * Create a file in root folder using MetadataChangeSet object.
     * @param result
     */
    public void CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result){
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside createfileongoogledrive method");
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello Joseph, you created me(: !");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("test2")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                // create a file in root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    /**
     * Handle result of Created file
     */
    final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file created: "+""+
                                result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    return;

                }
            };

    /**
     *  Handle Response of selected file
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param data
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                    final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    mFileId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

                    Log.e("file id", mFileId.getResourceId() + "");

                    String url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id="+ mFileId.getResourceId();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please talk about what you tried and what errors were raised, if any.  Also try to minimize how much code you ask people to go through.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have to use the ImageManager the Google Drive API has but not sure how to use it. I am unsure of how toretrieve the uri of the photo selected.

Comment: Consider using the Storage Access Framework (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)
, also see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171246/open-a-google-drive-file-content-uri-after-using-kitkat-storage-access-framework

Comment: @Anatoli will I still need the Google Drive API key for this?

Comment: @TheLearner no, it's a completely different mechanism.