# How to retrieve the original file

Tags: java, sql, file, blob

In Java JSP, I'm using input stream and BLOB datatype to write any type of file into the database. I want to retrieve the BLOB file. How should I go about retrieving it? I tried using select statement and got this (material column).
[image]

Comment: can you show some code, how you are inserting into the database ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203046/retrieving-file-upload-from-database) check the code

Answer (score 2):

Using a `ResultSet`, you can retrieve a `java.sql.Blob` instance:

```
Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("MATERIAL");
```

Then you can open an input stream:

```
InputStream input = blob.getBinaryStream();
```

And write it to a file as described in [Is it possible to create a File object from InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501418/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-object-from-inputstream)

Comment: how to show that input stream in jsp,after retrieving the value of blob material?

Comment: do you have to show it or be able to download it? what do you want to do if the file can't be showed?

Comment: i solved this without using blob, for downloads igave the filepath and it works

Answer (score 0):

Getting the Blob from the table:

```
try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query)) {
    if(rs.next()) {
        fileBlob = rs.getBlob(1);
    }
}
```

Saving the contents of the Blob into a new file:

```
try (InputStream ipStream = fileBlob.getBinaryStream(1, fileBlob.length());
        OutputStream opStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/file"))) {                        
    int c;
    while ((c = ipStream.read()) > -1) {
        opStream.write(c);
    }
}
```