# Converting InputStream to File Object

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to pass a `File` object while using `loadKeyMaterial()` api in Spring application. I am using a jar file to run my application, and have faced the problem when accessing the `File` directly in the jar.
So, I am using `InputStream` to access the File from the Resources.
How do I convert this `InputStream` to a `File` object for the `loadKeyMaterial()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a File object from InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501418/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-object-from-inputstream)

Comment: Indeed, but creating a temporary file somewhere with the keys sounds less than optimal. Sure, keys bundled in a jar are not very secure either, but one step better than putting them in the temp folder!

Comment: @anchreg
From the above link : 
Is it possible to create a File object from InputStream
they have mentioned to create File file = new File();
However, I have seen that we cannot access a file directly when we create a jar.
So I am not sure where to create that temp file in the resources folder.

Comment: @ewramner..so how to proceed with that approach ?

Comment: @pixelWorld, You can read/write files outside the JAR,  long as the user running the JVM process has the required permissions. Jiri Tousek's answers seems like a good fit, can you not use the overloaded method?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`loadKeyMaterial()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#loadKeyMaterial(java.security.KeyStore,%20char[])) overload that uses `KeyStore` rather than `File` parameter. The `KeyStore` may be loaded from a stream, there's an example for that in [KeyStore Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html?is-external=true).

Comment: I have to use the  SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial() api in order to initialize the SSLContext object, I don't see with the above workaround I can do that.