# Is there a way to get a file from InputStream

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream, outputstream

I'm currently reading a file with:

```
InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE);
```

Is there any way I can get the file from this `InputStream` so that I can later write to it.
Or is it possible to convert the `InputStream` into an `OutputStream` that will point to the exact same file?
I found out that `getResourceAsStream()` does not exist for `OutputStream`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a File object from InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501418/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-object-from-inputstream)

Comment: No do not need to create a new file and then copy the contents. I want to get the exact same file that the inputstream is referencing.

Comment: The InputStream doesn't have this information. More than that, a resource inside your application is not always even representable as a `File`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
File file = new File(MyClass.class.getResource(FILE).toURI());
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

It will work in IDE or if your app is a web app (war).
But if you are writing a jar app, it will not work when you build it, because the file will be in jar package, you can not write it this way. In this case you should store the FILE externally (not in resources).

Comment: This doesn't work if this resource is inside a JAR file, which is the usual case

Comment: There is no way to change resources in runtime. To edit file in jar archive you need to unpack it, rewrite file and pack it back. Even if you do these strange manipulations you won't be able to use the changed file, because JVM will have old jar loaded.

Comment: I know that, that is why I commented that your answer won't work in most cases.

Comment: The point of my answer was 'you should store the FILE externally (not in resources)'. If someone missed it, I'm sorry