# Java - Cast a byte array or String to (virtual) File

Tags: java, file, arrays, inputstream

**In short**: I want to **cast a byte array or String into a File object**, so that I can use this File object as a parameter for a method whose signature I can not change. I want to achieve this in-memory, without ever touching a drive.

I have read many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317035/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-virtual-file) here, including suggestions about using File.createTempFile, but I get the impression we're still creating physical files then, even if it's only temporary?

**In full**: I am helping with a very complex data recovery project. We now have a, let's say, disk image of over 400GB, which is a collection of 2MB-sections. Some of the files I want to recover begin in one, and end in another 2MB-section. We have an inventory of where we've seen beginnings and endings, so now I want to stitch beginnings and endings together, and then check whether the result is a valid file, in some propretary format. *(this is all background information, let's please not get into that!)*

I have a java class (that I can't change) that can read and therefore verify these files. So I want to simply feed my put-together-file into this method. If it is succesful, I move on to the next "begin-part", otherwise I try to match the begin-part with a different end-part.

I want to keep the 'stitched together files' in memory (not write it to temporary files) because it's probably clear that I need high efficiency. This is a last resort; indeed, we need to match many thousands of beginnings with many thousands of endings. But again, let's just keep to the question :)

Comment: A `java.io.File` only represents a path and filename, not the actual content of the file itself.

Comment: If your API takes a `java.io.File`, the only simple way I can think of is to use a RAM drive...

Comment: Hm, I suppose I will indeed need a RAM drive... sounds like there will be no other way if File can only ever point to 'an actual file'. Thanks!

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: I'm writing the program on Windows 7. I don't have easy access to another platform to work on... but I see there are many free utilities to create a RAM drive on Windows, too.

Comment: OK. I was asking because on Linux you would quite probably have a ram disk already in the form of `/tmp`. On many systems, that's backed by ram.

Comment: "I want to cast a byte array or String into a File object."  It does not compute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Java class accepts [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) that is, *file paths* in a file system, then yes, you have to create a file in a file system and then feed the Java class with the file path. You may speed up things by creating the file in RAM drive but nevertheless it's a file. If the class also accepts [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (well designed classes do), then you can use [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). Another possible interface of the class to accept input data is [Java NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html) machinery with [ReadableByteChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html) being the NIO analog for an abstract `java.io.InputStream`